# Kubuntu software center problem

Tags: 17.04

Hi guys I am new to kde and I am using kubuntu 17.04 and my problem is that when I try to install app from app store I got this error message (cannot obtain lock) so guys I hope you can help me with this issue and thanks for your time.

Comment: It means there are other process using it, probably the updates (that you should install).

Comment: Does the problem persist after a reboot?

Comment: Are you sure that the message is "cannot obtain lock"?

Comment: DK Bose yes I am sure.

Comment: MichaelBay I already updated the system and I can't use the sudo update command neither I got a similar problem can't find the lock file maybe other process is using it.e

Comment: NerdOfLinux no but after I update the system

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the terminal or on KDE "Konsole" and type in this command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and try again. :)

I hope this helps it works for me!